# install4j 8 and notarization for mac

Tags: install4j

Although intall4j 8 now supports notarization, it can only create notarized applications when actually run on a Mac.  Which does not help with cross-platform development.

Is there somewhere a cookbook on how to take a dmg built with install4j 8 on Windows and get it notarized?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because Apple requires that the upload is done from a Mac via the Xcode command line tools.

Comment: What I think would be a very attractive feature for install4j would be to for the Mac version to input a dmg package created by install4j windows and 'rebuild' it with the notarization  option in the Mac version.  Is that possible?

Comment: It is currently not possible, but we do have this in our issue tracker. However, you can use the Apple command line tools yourself on a Mac to notarize a DMG.

Comment: I've now spent two weeks trying to get through the Mac command line tools, just one roadblock after another.  For a 'cross platform development tool" this is most unsatisfactory.;

Comment: If you build on the mac, install4j will be able to do the notarization for you and you don't have to use the command line tools. Indeed, notarization is a cumbersome process and prevents a full cross-platform build if you have macOS media files. Unfortunately, it is Apple's legal and technical barriers that prevent us from performing this step on al platforms.